# Complete separation and stepwise regression - possible in R?

Tags: r, logistic, stepwise-regression, separation

I've been using stepAIC to narrow down my logistic regression model.  However, I get the following warning when I run my model:

glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

I know this means I have complete or quasi-complete separation in my data.  On examination of my data, I see the quasi-complete separation and think that it's meaningful.  Reading online, I see recommendations to use a Firth penalized regression (logistf) or exact logistic regression (elrm); but neither of these will work with stepAIC.  I've also tried bayesglm but I still get the same warning.

How should I select a model when my data has complete separation?  How would I do this in R?  Is my mistake in my stats or in my understanding of using the packages in R?  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You would do best not to do stepwise selection at all (cf., [Algorithms for automatic model selection](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20856/7290)).

Comment: The Hauck-Donner effect tag provides a number of very helpful answers on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

See [High p-values for logistic regression variable that perfectly separates?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/102695/17230) & [How to deal with perfect separation in logistic regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11109/17230) for some background. If stepwise selection were appropriate (take @gung's advice to read [Algorithms for automatic model selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20836/17230)), a straightforward approach would be just to make the decisions based on likelihood-ratio tests (equivalently AIC), as the Wald tests will be badly wrong.

Perhaps you could take a similar approach with Firth regression: Heinze & Schemper (2002), "A solution to the problem of separation in logistic regression", *Statist. Med.*, **21**, pp 2409–19, form a penalized log likelihood ratio test statistic for the null hypothesis that a given coefficient is zero analogously to the unpenalized version, & imply that its asymptotic distribution is also chi-square with one degree of freedom. (By the way, "problem" is rather a loaded term.)